# return to MainWindow after using adding a UserControl with .Child

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I switch to a userControl using .Child like so:

```
Grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
Stage.Child = new UserControlName();
```

Where `Grid1` is the grid where the content sits in the main window, (which should be hidden because there's some content that will peek out from behind the usercontrol), and `Stage` is a `border` element where I want the UserControl to fill

```
 <Grid >
    <Border x:Name="Stage" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="1200" Height="649" >
```

How can `UserControlName` be closed or hidden from its own `xaml.cs` file and the view be returned to the main window while simultaneously returning `MainWindow`'s `Grid1` to `Visible`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement that using Regions from PRISM (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098(v=pandp.40).aspx). But if you created simple application and you don't want to invest time to learn PRISM you can for example extend constructor of UserControlName class by adding parameter of MainWindow type and invoke on this object some method that would change the view to your desire state.
Example of uglly code:

MainWindow:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        br.Child = new UserControl2(this);
    }

    public void CloseView()
    {
        grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        br.Child = null;
    }
```

UserControl:

```
    private MainWindow window;
    public UserControl2(MainWindow window)
    {
        this.window = window;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window.CloseView();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use (for example) the Mvvm Light toolkit and messaging (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).

The child view would send a message to get closed, the main window would receive this message and hide the grid.

The advantage is that the main window and the child control are still uncoupled meaning that the child does not need to know anything about the main window.

Take this chance and invest some time in the Mvvm pattern and libraries such as Mvvm light.